# Connection failure - ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: database, connection

I've been looking all over the internet for an answer, and I didn't find anything.

I am trying på make a connection between Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and SQL Server Management Studio. I just made a small program just to see if the connection works.

Everytime I'm trying to connect, VS throws an `ODBCexception`.

> "ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server
>   on 'localhost' (10061)"

This is my connectionstring:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Data Source=MY-USERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MY-DATABASE;Integrated Security=True
```

This connection string was copied from a data connection I've made inside VS.

Do any one have the magic solution???

Please and thank you! :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're mixing the **MySQL** driver (`DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}`) with a Microsoft **SQL Server Express** server name (`Data Source=MY-USERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;`) - which one do you really want to connect to??

If you want to connect to **SQL Server Express** (which comes bundled with Visual Studio), you need to use the native .NET SQL client (and not the ODBC stuff).

In that case, your connection string would be something like:

```
server=YourMachine\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True
```

or something similar - see [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.ConnectionStrings.com) for tons of samples.

In this case, you should use classes like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace in your application.

Comment: OMG OMG OMG!!! YOU ARE JUST A LIFESAVER!!! My adrenaline is still pumping after 8 hours of trouble with this!! OMG!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

IT WORKS :D:D

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see the forest for the trees... bet we've all been there.... glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but here is to guide anyone who had a problem like mine. In setting up Diafaan SMS server, i had the same problem. The problem was in the syntax. Note that in declaring the Server, Database, User and Password do not use quotes. That is why the error says 'localhost' remove all the single quotes from your connection string.

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE= yourdatabase;User= root;Password = yourpassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 3306 port is not blocked even if you are connecting to a remote MySql database. I got into same issue and it resolved once we opened the 3306 port.